# Solving a real integral using Cauchy theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

How do I compute the residues of the complex function in order to evaluate the following real integral using Cauchy's theorem?

$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dE \left[\frac{E^2f(E)}{(E-E_n-i\eta)^2(E-E_m-i\eta)}  -\frac{E^2f(E)}{(E-E_n+i\eta)^2(E-E_m+i\eta)} \right]
$$
In the above expression, $f(E)=\frac{1}{e^{\beta E}-1}$, and $E_n$, $E_m$, and $\eta$ are real positive numbers. I believe that constructing a contour on the upper half of the complex plane will lead to contributions only from the first term of the integrand, as its poles at $E_n+i\eta$ and $E_m+i\eta$ will lie inside the contour. However, I am struggling to determine how to calculate the residues for this complex equation.

Comment: What is $\beta$?

Comment: @Accelerator  I guess this integral comes from statistical mechanics, so that $\beta = \frac{1}{k_BT}$ is the inverse temperature.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no trick in that case, apart from partial fraction decomposition and residues. Have you tried to carry those computations ?

Comment: I tried to. Well, I didn't write down anything, actually. I just tried to picture in my head what kind of technique would work here. Residue theory might be possible here but the issue is that there are infinitely many singularities of the form $z = i\frac{2\pi n}{\beta}$ for all integers $n$.

Comment: @Accelerator  A (countably) infinite number of singularities is not a problem *per se*; sum all the residues and hope the series will converge.